# Disk Space in Linux Server

Tags: linux

How do we check the disk space left in a disk.
Suppose if we have total disk space as below

```
[root@abc ~]# fdisk -l|grep Disk
```

Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250058268160 bytes

How do we find how much is free in this 250GB disk.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Apparently you want the unused partitions, which `fdisk -l` does report. And you could have some partitions with a filesystem on it which is not mounted....

Answer (score 83):

You should use `df -h`

```
$ man df
df - report file system disk space usage
```

You can add the `--total` option to have the total. For example:

```
$ df -h --total
...
...
total             135G   79G   51G  61% -
```

Comment: I want to know the total free space in the disk. Not the free space of mounted partitions. Total free space including those not yet allocated.

Comment: This answer is not always true. If you run some docker containers in your system, it will report the wrong total.

Comment: @Annahri Why would it be wrong if you are running docker containers?

Comment: @L_H Because it will also take account of overlayfs used by docker containers, which results in wrong total size output.

Answer (score 14):

Use `df -h` .This command will display the file system disk space usage.

```
$ df -h
```

The above command will display the disk size details on terminal.

For Ex:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda
                       20G   14G  4.6G  76% /
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
```

Here the Total disk size is 20G, Used is 14G and `Free is 4.6G`.

Answer (score 2):

use

> df -h

more details are available at this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 2):

You can use several commands

```
df -h
```

Link: [more commands](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/22.html)

Comment: link is not for disk space commands

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanna check, use "df"

df -h lists all devices with human readable formats, but of course you can say 'df /dev/sda' to get the exact numbers.